# Android ViewModel Obserable not Observed

Tags: android, kotlin

I am creating an app that using Android Architecture Components Navigation and ViewModel. It has a navigation to fragment that as tab layout, the menu is called MyProductFragment, and inside this MyProductFragment i have MyProductItemFragment and MyProductCategoryFragment. MyroductItemFragment is displaying the list of prodduct and category is displaying the categories, the scenario is when i click the category, it will call query to database to filter data, and turn the filtered data to viemodel then the MyProductItemFragment will observe that, but it seems not working.
Here is my MyProduct Fragment oncreate

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                          container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val productViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(context as FragmentActivity)[ProductViewModel::class.java]
    productViewModel.setProductList(null)
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menus_my_product, container, false)

    ToolKt.loadFragment(myProductItemFragment, childFragmentManager,savedInstanceState)

    val tabLayout = root.findViewById<TabLayout>(R.id.tab_layout)
    InitToolbar.setTabLayout(tabLayout) { tab ->
        if (tab.position == 0) {
            ToolKt.loadFragment(myProductItemFragment, childFragmentManager)
        } else if (tab.position == 1) {
            ToolKt.loadFragment(myProductCategoryFragment, childFragmentManager)
        }
    }

    return root
}
```

here is my MyProductItemFragment method that call the viewModel

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val token = SharedPrefManager.getInstance(requireContext()).merchantInfo
    val idMerchant = ToolKt.getIdMerchant(token)!!
    var productList:List<ProductModel>?=null
    val viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(context as FragmentActivity)[ProductViewModel::class.java]
    viewmodel.getProductList().observe(this, Observer {
        productList = it
    })
    if(productList.isNullOrEmpty()){
        doAsync {
            productList = RoomSingleton.getInstance(requireContext()).productDao().gets(idMerchant)
            val productAdapter = ProductAdapter(productList!!,{ item:ProductModel->onItemClick(item)})
            Log.e("PC",productList.toString())
            activity?.runOnUiThread(Runnable {
                RecyclerViewManagement.setAdapterLinearVerticalDivider(requireContext(),rv_product,productAdapter)
            })
        }

    }
    else{
        val productAdapter = ProductAdapter(productList!!,{ item:ProductModel->onItemClick(item)})
        RecyclerViewManagement.setAdapterLinearVerticalDivider(requireContext(),rv_product,productAdapter)
    }

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_product, container, false)
}
```

and my MyProductCategoryFragment

```
private fun itemClicked(item:ProductCategoryModel,view:View){
    Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"Mengklik category ${item.name} id ${item.id}",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    val viewmodel = ViewModelProviders.of(context as FragmentActivity)[ProductViewModel::class.java]
    doAsync {
        val filteredProduct = RoomSingleton.getInstance(requireContext()).productDao().getByCategory(idMerchant!!,item.id)
        Log.e("Filtered",filteredProduct.toString())
        activity?.runOnUiThread {
            viewmodel.setProductList(filteredProduct)
            Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.navigation_product)
        }
    }


}
```

my viewModel

```
class ProductViewModel:ViewModel() {
private val productList = MutableLiveData<List<ProductModel>>()
fun getProductList(): LiveData<List<ProductModel>> {
    return productList
}
fun setProductList(data:List<ProductModel>?){
    productList.value=data
}
```

}

Everything is ok, data filtered as well, the only problem is that filtered data is not observed, what is wrong?

Comment: Hello Can you share your view model class?

Comment: @DeepakRajput i've updated my question, please kindly check it out

Comment: Can you try this in your view model class:   productList.postvalue(data)

Comment: And also observe like this :  viewmodel.getProductList().observe(this, Observer<List<ProductModel>> {
        productList = it
    })

Comment: still notworking

Comment: How do you know the observable is not observed? Have you tried debugging and setting a breakpoint inside the `Observer` or just assumed that based on the fact that  the UI didn't changed?

Comment: after debugging, it was observed, but it not change the adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LiveData` follows the observer pattern which means that when its value changes, the proper `Observer` gets informed, so it can e.g. execute some tasks based on the new value:

```
val liveData: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()

liveData.observe(owner, Observer {
    println(it) // when the value changes, the Observer prints it
})

liveData.value = 2
// printed: 2

liveData.value = 3
// printed: 3
```

If you want to change your UI on every `LiveData` value update, you have to put the proper logic **inside** the `Observer`:

```
viewmodel.getProductList().observe(this, Observer {
    productList = it

    if(productList.isNullOrEmpty()){
        doAsync {
            productList = RoomSingleton.getInstance(requireContext()).productDao().gets(idMerchant)
            val productAdapter = ProductAdapter(productList!!, { item:ProductModel -> onItemClick(item) })
            Log.e("PC", productList.toString())
            activity?.runOnUiThread(Runnable {
                RecyclerViewManagement.setAdapterLinearVerticalDivider(requireContext(), rv_product, productAdapter)
            })
        }
    } else {
        val productAdapter = ProductAdapter(productList!!, { item: ProductModel -> onItemClick(item) })
        RecyclerViewManagement.setAdapterLinearVerticalDivider(requireContext(), rv_product, productAdapter)
    }

})
```